# JSON schema pattern validation is failing

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, jsonschema

I am using below pattern in json schema to validate strings.

```
"pattern": "^(nfs://)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):([0-9]{4})"
```

But currently it is not validating "nfs://172.1.1:2049" as invalid string.

Comment: Why does port number have to be four digits? That seems like an error. It could very well be anywhere from 2-5. As far as [a regular expression tester](https://regex101.com) goes, this should work.

Comment: The issue is with ip address. The pattern is matching even if i give only 3 parts of ip.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Javascript json-scema validation.

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to match 4 groups of numbers between 0 and 255 but `172.1.1` only contains 3 groups.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't immediately seem like an obvious problem, but the `.` character needs to be escaped because you're trying to literally match that character.

This regex, with escaped `.` and forward slashes works:

```
^(nfs:\/\/)(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):([0-9]{4})
```

The problem was that since each capturing group that matches digits can match as few as one digit or as many as three, the regex engine looked at the first `1` (in `172`), found that it was valid, then tried matching `.`  (any character) and found the digit `7`, which is not what you want.

In `nfs://172.1.1:2049`, the second capturing group in your regex matched the first `1` in the IP address, the `.` matched the `7`, the third capturing group matched the `2`.. and so on.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/TNXDiQ/1